# Initiate soft reload of scalastyle_config.xml in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalastyle

IntelliJ's Scala plugin comes with support for [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) and provides this guidance:

> Scalastyle examines your Scala code and indicates potential problems with it.
>
> Place scalastyle_config.xml in the root/.idea or root/project directory.

However, when I make changes to my local `scalastyle_config.xml` file IntelliJ does not automatically detect the changes and apply them to the code I am editing.

I have found that if I close and re-open my IntelliJ project it will indeed reload this file and apply the rules to my code but this is a very heavy-handed and lengthy approach.

How do you initiate an IntelliJ reload of `scalastyle_config.xml` when the file has changed?

Comment: have you added the plugin into your project?

Comment: I believe so. When my code breaks a rule from the file, IntelliJ highlights the infraction and reports the details, attributing them to scalastyle.

Comment: Doesn't it help to run "File | Synchronize"?

Comment: No it doesn't :/